# Can someone help me with my code problem?

Tags: python

> Write a function called check_values that has three parameters: `x`, `y`, and `z`. Every value passed to each of these parameters will be an integer. This function should return `True` if all three variables sum to a positive number or if at least two of the variables hold positive values. Otherwise this function should return `False`.

Below is my code:

```
def check_values(x, y, z):
    if x+y+z >= 0:
        return True
    elif (x or y >=0) or (y or z >=0) or (x or z >= 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    x = int(input('Enter X value: '))
    y = int(input('Enter Y value: '))
    Z = int(input('Enter Z value: '))
```

I failed this assert check:

```
assert not check_values(1, -1, -1), "this should return False, not True (or any other value)"
```

How do I fix this? Also is there a better way to do the check "if at least two of the variables hold positive values"?

Comment: `x and y >= 0` will not compare `x` with 0.

Comment: Could you give your question a more helpful title? Readers shouldn't have to click through to the question to see what it's about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `elif` statement does not work this way.
You should write:
`elif (x>=0 and y>=0) or ...:`

Does this help?